# Radio button background image is not centered in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am designing custom radio button with css3.

Here is my code below:

```css
.form-checked:checked[type=radio]{
    background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' viewBox='0 0 24 24'%3E%3Cg fill='none'%3E%3Cpath d='M12 16a4 4 0 1 0 0-8a4 4 0 0 0 0 8z' fill='%23626262'/%3E%3Cpath fill-rule='' clip-rule='' d='M22 12c0 5.523-4.477 10-10 10S2 17.523 2 12S6.477 2 12 2s10 4.477 10 10zm-2 0a8 8 0 1 1-16 0a8 8 0 0 1 16 0z' fill='rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}
```

But the background image doesn't seem to be centered in with Chrome. (Even lastest version)

Here is how it looks like in [chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cGUB.jpg)

But it works perfectly fine on other browsers like [firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bG3JU.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should disable default Google Chrome styling. Maybe it's causing the problem.
Example: https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/css/remove+default+chrome+checkbox+styling

Comment: Thanks for your comment but I solved. Problem is at Webkit's background-origin property.  Correct code is as this.  .radio-button:checked{background-image:url(...); background-origin:border-box;}